# Mahout Content Based Recommendation Engine

Tags: algorithm, mongodb, hadoop, mahout, mahout-recommender

I am working on a recommendation problem (Content based recommendation). I have my data set in mongodb in  json format.

**Problem Statement**
There are items which have their own properties, and users have some preference regarding each properties. Now I am thinking to predict how much the item x will be liked by the user based on the properties of item and comparing the preferences of the user for same properties that item x have.  I want to build a recommendation system to recommend the items to user , based on their preference.

I am thinking of using Mahout and CBAYES Classifier algorithm to predict , "how much item x will be liked by User A ". But I haven't found any example and data set for implementing CBAYES using mahout.

If you have any other suggestion to use any other classifier algorithm then please recommend.

Comment: What actually troubles me with your question, framework aside of course, is how are you intending to use the Complementary Naive Bayes classifier as a recommender algorithm. Could you explain please? And what is your actual question? So would be helpful too!

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate “how much item x will be liked by User A” by using cosine similarity.  Please refer the following link for your more information.

Reference link:  [What's difference between Collaborative Filtering Item-based recommendation and Content-based recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16372191/whats-difference-between-collaborative-filtering-item-based-recommendation-and)

Regards,

Rajasekar